# Chaining animated sequences for an infinite loop presentation

Tags: jquery, html, loops, presentation

I'm coding up a presentation for display on a TV in the office reception area and need some help please.

I've tried numerous StackOverflow answers to try and resolve this, but none relate particularly well to my situation. I have spent *days* trying to solve this and am ready to quit.

Here's the main bulk of the script:

```
    var startDelay =  5;   //  time in seconds before the directors image sequence begins (default 120 secs)
    var cycleDelay = 10;     // time in seconds after the end of director bios sequence completes and the directors image sequence begins again (default 240 secs)
    var biosDelay =  2;     // time in seconds to show each of the director bios in the carousel (default 10 secs, with total squence time 60 secs)

// start the directors image sequence after a few seconds
    //var tid = window.setTimeout(playDirectors, (startDelay*1000));
    // this was commented out to eliminate interval/timeout problems
    // the presentation is started at the bottom of the script
    // by calling the playDirectors() function immediately, 
    // instead of after the startDelay period

// directors slideshow 
    function playDirectors(){
    //alert("playDirectors");

    // fade out the white client list
        $('#client-qtrotator').fadeTo(500,0, function(){ 
            $("#client-qtrotator").cycle("pause");
         }); 

    // fade up the directors image container then begin image ripple sequence
        $("#directors").fadeTo(500,1,imgFader);
    };

// begin directors image ripple sequence
    function imgFader(){ 
        // label each photo using the alt text        
            $('.banner li img').each(function(i){
                var imageAlt = $(this).attr("alt");
                $(this).after("<span class='caption'>"+imageAlt+"</span>");
             });

        var elm = $('#directors ul.banner li');

        $( elm ).each(function( n ) {
            $( this ).delay(500*n).fadeTo(1000,1).delay(5000).fadeTo(1000,0);
            });

        var def = $(elm).promise();
            def.done(
               function () {
                  //alert('done');
                  playDirectorsBios();
            });

    };

// directors bios slideshow 
    function playDirectorsBios(){
        //alert("playDirectorsBios");

        // fade out directors image container
            $("#directors").fadeTo(500,0);

        // fade in the directors bios carousel
            $('#directors-bios').fadeTo(500,1);//.delay(19000).fadeTo(500,0, alert("done!"));

        // begin cycling through the director bios
            $('.cycle-bios').cycle({
                fx: "scrollHorz",
                slides: "> div",
                loop: 1,
                timeout: biosDelay*1000
            });

        // when the bios have finished playing
            $( '.cycle-bios' ).on( 'cycle-finished', function( event, opts ) {
                // alert("bios finished");
                $(this).cycle('pause'); 

                // fade out  the directors bios carousel
                $('#directors-bios').fadeTo(500,0, function() {
                       // animation complete
                       // $('#client-qtrotator').delay(1000).fadeTo(500,1);
                       $('.cycle-bios').cycle('destroy');

                    var def2 = $('#directors-bios').delay(cycleDelay*1000).promise();
                        def2.done(
                           function () {
                              //alert('done bios');
                              playDirectors();
                        });

                // fade the cloud back in
                    $("#myCanvasContainer").delay(500).fadeTo(2000,1);

                // fade the client list back up
                    $('#client-qtrotator').delay(1000).fadeTo(500,1, function(){ 
                        $("#client-qtrotator").delay(500).cycle("resume"); // resume the client list cycle
                 });  

            });
    };

// begin the presentation by playing the directors image slideshow
playDirectors();
```

Please view the current iteration over here:
http://duncanmcphail.com.au/tv2.shtml

*I have resorted to trying "jquery-timing", but without much success - tbh, I think I'm just introducing new problems... :(*

Here's the **tl;dr version** of the presentation sequence...

1. Fade out the large white client list
2. Fade in the directors images, one after the other, hold each for 5 seconds, then fade out.
3. Fade in the directors bios, and begin the sliding carousel cycle
4. Fade out the carousel cycle after the last bio
5. Wait several seconds before beginning the directors images sequence again
6. Repeat from Step 1

Here's a **lengthy breakdown** of what is supposed to occur...

There are several elements to the presentation - ignore the top region with "Our professional services..." cycling through, and the bottom region with an RSS feed ticking over.

I'm using the *Cycle2* script to handle effects on multiple list items and `fadeTo` in preference of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to bring the main elements in and out of the sequence.

In the middle region, I am cycling through a list of client names in large white text - this is working fine.

Then, after a `startDelay` period, I fade out the white names, pause that cycle, then fade up a container which includes a list of images of each company director.

Each director's image fades in, holds for 5 seconds, then fades out, creating a ripple effect.

When the last director's image fades out, I fade out the container and immediately fade up another container which includes an animated carousel of each director with their bios.

When the bios sequence completes, its container fades out, the client names fade back up and resume cycling, and a `cycleDelay` begins, to postpone the directors image sequence before it runs again.

So far, I thought I had everything chained correctly but I cannot resolve a problem with the director's images sequence.

After two cycles of the director's images sequence, followed by the bios sequence, the third cycle of the images begins, except this time, instead of the ripple effect playing as normal, the first list image begins to fade back up as the second list image begins its fade out, producing a staggered effect in what should be a smooth ripple. This continues to get worse as the presentation cycles through each sequence.

I think that this sequence is being triggered repeatedly, such that there becomes multiple instances of it running - testing on Chrome, eventually the browser will crash.

I've tried everything from `setInterval` and `setTimeout` to `when()`, `promise()`, `done()`, etc. etc. etc. and the problem remains. My knowledge isn't advanced enough to determine where or why this is failing, so my last resort is to consult some experts and hope they can spot my problem or suggest another way to do this.

Thank you for reading.

**Update:**

I've re-written 90% of the script, having resorted to using *jquery-timing* to create this:

```
$('#directors ul.banner li').each($).animate({ opacity:1 },500,$).wait(event).all().wait(3000).each($).animate({ opacity:0 },500,$);
```

Basically, each image fades up over 500ms, waits for 3000ms and then fades out over 500ms - I then need to fire my next function after the last image has faded out.

After going through the documentation and examples at http://creativecouple.github.io/jquery-timing/documentation/ I have not been able to trigger a function once the animation completes.

How should I rewrite the above code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What I used in my project that help me with the timing and chaining sequences is this

https://sjp.co.nz/projects/timing-manager/

Just read the text thoroughly and you will achieve perfect timing.

Here is a more detailed documentation.

https://github.com/sjp/TimingManager

Just ignore the R topic and just use plain javascript. It worked for me so It should work  for you too.

Comment: I you had a hard time making it work. I'll be happy too share the link to my project privately. This is a confidential project so I cannot share it publicly.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance agentpx, I've reverted to "jquery-timing" because "timing-manager" is way over my head. I've added an update to my original question - if you don't mind, can you please explain how to trigger a function after the sequence has completed?

Comment: I believe the function you need to trigger must be included  in your  sequence also. The reason is your animation will execute along with the function you intend to trigger if you don't add it to the sequence.  I can help you with the timing manager if you will tell me your challenges bout the library.